# Undefined local variable or method params in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rspec-rails, parameters

Hi I am implementing a method to delete a user account in my web application. My controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :set_current_user

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:user_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def delete_account
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        if @user.present?
            @user.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "User Account Deleted."
        end
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    def destroy
        User.delete(:user_id)
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

My rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'
require'factory_girl'

describe UsersController do
   describe "delete account" do

        before :each do
            @fake_results = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        end

        it "should call the model method that find the user" do
            expect(User).to receive(:find).with(params[:id]).and_return (@fake_results)
        end

        it "should destroy the user account from the database" do
            expect{delete :destroy, id: @fake_results}.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
        end

        it "should redirect_to the home page" do
           expect(response).to render_template(:home)
        end

   end 
end
```

1. The first error is

   ```
   Failure/Error: expect(User).to receive(:find).with(params[:id]).and_return (@fake_results)

   NameError:undefined local variable or method `params' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersController::DeleteAccount:0x00000007032e18>
   ```

I know what this error means but I don't know how to correct it. How can I pass the user id from the controller to rspec?

2. The second error is:

   ```
   Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:home)
   expecting <"home"> but rendering with <[]>
   ```

I think there is something wrong with my controller method. It should redirect to the home page but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is not available in your tests, it's available in your controller.

Looks like you create a test user in your test:

```
@fake_results = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Then, you can use the `id` of this test user (`@fake_results.id`) instead of trying to use `params[:id]`:

```
expect(User).to receive(:find).with(@fake_results.id).and_return (@fake_results)
```

Although, you may want to change the name from `@fake_results` to something more meaningful e.g. `test_user` or so.

However, this should fix both of your problems as your second problem is there because of the first problem. As it's failing to delete the user in the first place, it's not being redirected to the root path and hence the `home` template is not rendering.

Comment: Actually I want to make sure the model method receive the id of my current user, find it out and delete it. In the test, I can return a test_user and delete it. But how can I test if my model method receive the current user's id?

Comment: In that case, you have to implement user login for your tests and then make your user login inside the test and then delete the user using his id.